# Create a global counter in a NodeJS module

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create unique ids for my React components. I have created this modules:

```
var _uid = 0;

function getUid(): {
    ++_uid;
    return `_uid_${_uid}`;
}

export default getUid;
```

Hoping that the `_uid` would be increased every time the module function is called, but it is always 1. How can I achieve increase it every time the module is required?

Comment: `var _uid: number = 0;` is not regular Javascript.  Do you mean to me using some other language?

Comment: @jfriend00 well it is Flow, but it compiles to JavaScript. Sorry, I forgot the type annotation there!

Comment: Then please tag it with the appropriate language.

Comment: @jfriend00 I removed the type annotations. It is JavaScript now.

Answer (score 0):

Java script closure helps you there:

```
    var getUid = (function(){
       var _uid: number = 0;
       return function(){ 
        ++_uid;
        return `_uid_${_uid}`;
       }
    })();

export default getUid;
```

Comment: here _uid intilised only once as it is in anonymous function and i call it once and it return inner function to getUid, so after that when ever you require getUid it will only increment the existing value

Comment: It is not clear how this does anything different than the OP's original code.

Comment: This does not work. I tested it now and it does the same thing, `_uid` is always 1. Is there any way of achieving this at least? I think I will end up storing the index in `window._uid`.